# MatLab 2014a Fuzzy Toolbox Error

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to devise a Sugeno fuzzy system using the fuzzy GUI - for some reason when I add more than one output variable I get errors:

```
    Error using length
Too many input arguments.

Error in addvar (line 76)
        for ct=1:length(out.output.mf)

Error in fuzzy (line 746)
    fis=addvar(fis,varType,'',[0 1],'init');

Error while evaluating uimenu Callback
```

I'm using 2014a on a Mac running Mavericks.  To note, I also have 2013a installed on a MacBook and tried adding the same input and output variables and I get them same error messages.

If you add more than one output variable, then try and add input variable the above messages are then displayed within the command prompt.

Comment: I don'T know much about fuzzy stuff, but here is an uneducated guess based on a similar problem I had with structures: what if you try using either length(out(1).output.mf) or length(out.output(1).mf).

Comment: Thats the weird thing, is that I'm not using any code, I'm using the GUI `fuzzy`.  I've put in a service request with MATLAB, they have got back to me and said its a bug, and they have passed the problem on to technical support, etc.  The work around is to create all the input variables first, then create the output variables.  Tbh, I going to learn how to hard code everything in so I don't have to use the GUI as much.

Comment: Mhh ok interesting thanks for sharing!